# Connect to impala using python from Windows machine. Error: 'TSocket' object has no attribute 'isOpen'

Tags: python, impala

I want to access impala using python 3.7.3 (Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook) on my Windows machine.

The following code I am trying to execute:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
import traceback

try:
    conn = connect(host='myhost.xx.yy', port=21050, auth_mechanism="GSSAPI", \
                     user='userxx', password='password_xx')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "show databases;"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    print(cursor.fetchall())
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'TSocket' object has no attribute 'isOpen'
```